# How do I know which plugin is using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins, uiwebviewdelegate

When I execute grep -R UIWebView * in this directory:
Users/anonymous/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-04-16/app name 4-16-21, 3.42 PM.xcarchive

I get the following results:

```js
Binary file Products/Applications/app name.app/App Name matches
Binary file dSYMs/App Name.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/App Name matches
```

I'm not sure what that means...I received that from Apple support but how do I identify the plugin causing the issue?

When I run the same cmd from the following location:
Users/anonymous/project/app-name-v5/platforms/ios

```js
Binary file build/emulator/Heathen Mingle.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/App Name matches
build/sharedpch/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/6177444177259162338/App Name-Prefix.pch.d:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIWebView.h \
```

None of those are helping me identify which plugin has UIWebView included.  My app keeps getting rejected by Apple for having UIWebView but I'm not sure which plugin still contains it.

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-messaging": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.1.1",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.6",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "geofirex": "^0.1.0",
    "ionicons": "^4.5.10-0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
```

I've upgraded all of them and I've removed Google +

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ionic's official blog post](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/) on the topic if you haven't already. It covers all the steps and notes which Cordova plugins may still trigger the rejection.

Some suggestions:

- Firebase - consider migrating to [Cap Community firebase plugins](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/).
- Nothing else stands out. Broadly speaking, review your plugin list - which ones interact with a WebView and/or the webview apis?